# How to concatenate gathered data using mpi4py library in python

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing, mpi4py

I used to list  append of data employing `mpi4py` and try to save the data sequentially at the source(`root==0`) node.

As suggested by Alan22, I've modified the code and it works, but the script does not concatenate properly, so I get the output file as shown in attached figure:01.

Can anybody help how to fix the error message? In addition, whatever I've written in python script [shown below], isn't the best way to solve the problem. [image: saved output array]

Is there any way to solve this type of problem efficiently? Any help is highly appreciated.

The python script is given as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal
from mpi4py import MPI  
import random
import cmath, math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

#File storing path
save_results_to = 'File storing path'
```

```python
count_day = 1
count_hour = 1

arr_x = [0, 8.49, 0.0, -8.49, -12.0, -8.49, -0.0, 8.49, 12.0]
arr_y = [0, 8.49, 12.0, 8.49, 0.0, -8.49, -12.0, -8.49, -0.0]
M = len(arr_x)
N = len(arr_y)

np.random.seed(12345)
total_rows = 50000
raw_data=np.reshape(np.random.rand(total_rows*N),(total_rows,N))

# Function of CSD:: Using For Loop
fs = 500;       # Sampling frequency
def csdMat(data):
    dat, cols = data.shape   # For 2D data
    total_csd = []
    for i in range(cols):
        col_csd =[]
        for j in range( cols):
            freq, Pxy = signal.csd(data[:,i], data[:, j], fs=fs, window='hann', nperseg=100, noverlap=70, nfft=5000) 
            col_csd.append(Pxy)  
        total_csd.append(col_csd)
        pxy = np.array(total_csd)
    return freq, pxy

# Finding cross spectral density (CSD)
t0 = time.time()
freq, csd = csdMat(raw_data)
print('The shape of the csd data', csd.shape)
print('Time required {} seconds to execute CSD--For loop'.format(time.time()-t0))

kf=1*2*np.pi/10
resolution = 50 # This is important:: the HIGHER the Resolution, the higher the execution time!!!
grid_size = N * resolution
kx = np.linspace(-kf, kf, )  # space vector
ky = np.linspace(-kf, kf, grid_size)  # space vector

def DFT2D(data):
    P=len(kx)
    Q=len(ky)
    dft2d = np.zeros((P,Q), dtype=complex)
    for k in range(P):
        for l in range(Q):
            sum_log = []
            mat2d = np.zeros((M,N))
            sum_matrix = 0.0
            for m in range(M):
                for n in range(N):
                    e = cmath.exp(-1j*((((dx[m]-dx[n])*kx[l])/1) + (((dy[m]-dy[n])*ky[k])/1)))
                    sum_matrix += data[m, n] * e
            dft2d[k,l] = sum_matrix
    return dft2d

dx = arr_x[:]; dy = arr_y[:]


comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()
```

```python
data = []
start_freq = 100
end_freq   = 109
freq_range = np.arange(start_freq,end_freq)
no_of_freq = len(freq_range)

for fr_count in range(start_freq, end_freq):
    if fr_count % size == rank:
        dft = np.zeros((grid_size, grid_size))
        spec_csd = csd[:,:, fr_count]
        dft = DFT2D(spec_csd)  # Call the DFT2D function
        spec = np.array(np.real(dft))  # Spectrum or 2D_DFT of data[real part]
        print('Shape of spec', spec.shape)
        data.append(spec)
        #data = np.append(data,spec)
        np.seterr(invalid='ignore')
data = comm.gather(data, root =0)
#    comm.Allreduce(MPI.IN_PLACE,data,op=MPI.MAX)
print("Rank: ", rank, ". Spectrum shape is:\n", spec.shape)


if rank == 0:
    output_data = np.concatenate(data, axis = 0)
    #output_data = np.c_(data, axis = 0)
    dft_tot = np.array((output_data), dtype='object')
    res = np.zeros((grid_size, grid_size))
    for k in range(size):
        for i in range(no_of_freq):

            jj = np.around(freq[freq_range[i]], decimals = 2)

            #print('The shape of data after indexing', data1.shape)
            #data_final=data1.reshape(data1.shape[0]*data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2])
            res[i * size + k] = dft_tot[k][i] #np.array(data[k])
            data = np.array(res)
            #print('The shape of the dft at root node', data.shape)
            np.savetxt(save_results_to + f'Day_{count_day}_hour_{count_hour}_f_{jj}_hz.txt', data.view(float))
```

I use the following bash script command to run the script ( i.e., `my_file.sh`). I submit the job with command `sbatch my_file.sh`

```bash
#! /bin/bash -l
#SBATCH -J testmvapich2
#SBATCH -N 1 ## Maximum 04 nodes
#SBATCH --ntasks=10
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1        # cpu-cores per task
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=3000MB
#SBATCH --time=00:20:00
#SBATCH -p para
#SBATCH --output="stdout.txt"
#SBATCH --error="stderr.txt"
#SBATCH -A camk
##SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
##SBATCH --chdir=/work/cluster_computer/my_name/data_work/MMC331/


eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate myenv
#conda activate fast-mpi4py

cd $SLURM_SUBMIT_DIR

#module purge
#module add mpi/mvapich2-2.2-x86_64

mpirun python3 mpi_test.py
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: code give me `NameError: name 'freq' is not defined`. Create minimal working code which we could copy and run.

Comment: @furas; firstly thanks for the response. Now, I provide all the parameters to run the script. Can you please try for another attempt? When I change the range of 'For loop' then the script does not work.

Comment: You set `P=len(kx)` and `Q=len(ky)`. Then you use loops `k in range(P)` and `l in range(Q)`. Then you have tried to access `kx[l]` and `ky[k]`, when it should in fact be `kx[k]` and `ky[l]`. With this change, the code runs on my system.

Comment: @RoshanSam thanks for the reply. You are right, but it is not a problem here, as the length of [k] and [l] are equal. The problem starts from the concatenation just after the comm.gather (I think), the output data has not concatenated properly.

Comment: @CEB please try with `freq_range = np.arange(start_freq,end_freq+1)` instead of `freq_range = np.arange(start_freq,end_freq)` and similarly, in the loop, use `for fr_count in range(start_freq, end_freq+1)` instead of `for fr_count in range(start_freq, end_freq)`. Python range does not include last point.

Comment: @RoshanSam, thanks again and you are right. But at this moment, I'm interested on 'no_of_freq=10' so "freq_range = np.arange(start_freq,end_freq)" gives 10 steps while 'freq_range = np.arange(start_freq,end_freq+1)' gives 11 steps. Can you please suggest on the 'comm.gather' or concatenation as after concatenation the 'output_data' shape is OK but there are no data in the 'output_data' as shown in the attached figure.

Comment: @CEB for `start_freq = 100` and `end_freq = 109`, are you sure `freq_range = np.arange(start_freq,end_freq+1)` gives 11 steps?

Comment: @RoshanSam,sorry I need to correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245548/discussion-between-ceb-and-roshan-sam).

Comment: @RoshanSam, I have checked the output_data has not concatenated properly. So, the output data contains a lot of preallocated "list of zeros" though the the shape of output_data = (grid_size, grid_size). The grid_size = no_of_sensors*resolution. Here no_of_sensors=9 and resolution=50, so the grid_size is 9*50=450. Thanks

Comment: @furas, as a python expert, can you suggest a smart way for final output array indexing?

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this after "data = comm.gather(data, root=0)"

```html
if rank == 0:
    print('Type of data:', type(data))
    dft_tot = np.array((data))#, dtype='object')
    print('shape of DATA array:', dft_tot.shape)
    #print('Type of dft array:', type(dft_tot))
    res = np.zeros((450,450))
    for k in range(size):
#            for i in range(len(data[rank])):
        for i in range(no_of_freq):

            jj = np.around(freq[freq_range[k]], decimals = 2)
            #data1 = np.array(dft_tot[k])
            res[i * size + k] = data[k]
            data = np.array(res)#.reshape(data1.shape[0]*data1.shape[1], data1.shape[2])
            print('The shape of the dft at root node', data.shape)
            np.savetxt(save_results_to + f'Day_{count_day}_hour_{co
```

Here is the link. Hope it helps [mpi4py on HPC: comm.gather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359727/mpi4py-on-hpc-comm-gather)

Comment: Thanks. But it gives me error message due to indexing.    `res[i * size + k] =np.asarray(data[k])`
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,450,450) into shape (450,)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, there are two typos in the code:

1. The indices for arrays `kx` and `ky` have been swapped in the line where variable `e` is calculated in the function `DFT2D(data)`.
2. The code is being run for 10 MPI processes for frequencies `fr_count` in the range `start_freq = 100` and `end_freq = 109`. For this, the loops and `arange` must be written as `for fr_count in range(start_freq, end_freq + 1)` and `freq_range = np.arange(start_freq, end_freq + 1)` as these are not end-point inclusive.

The `data = comm.gather(data, root=0)` and subsequent `output_data = np.concatenate(data, axis=0)` operations are performing as they should and as such, the question detracts from the actual issue in the code.

A major issue is that in line `res[i * size + k] = dft_tot[k][i]` arrays of disparate sizes are being assigned to each other.

1. Shape of `res`: `450 x 450`
2. Shape of `dft_tot`: `10 x 50 x 450`

The value of `i*size + k` ranges from 0 to 110. I think the user expects `dft_tot` to have the shape `450 x 450`, probably due to the indexing confusion mentioned in typo#2 above. Properly done concatenation would yield `dft_tot` with shape `500 x 450` (since there are 10 arrays of size `50 x 450`).

Currently the `gather` operation returns a list of lists, each containing a NumPy array of size `50 x 450`. Technically, it should return a list of NumPy arrays each of size `50 x 450`. Adding the line `data = data[0]` (since `data` has only one element anyway in each process) before performing `data = comm.gather(data, root=0)` will achieve this result.

**But this whole process seems redundant..**

Because there are 10 frequencies considered here. For each frequency, there is a data set of size `50 x 450` . There are 10 MPI processes with each handling one frequency out of the 10. Finally, 10 files are being written corresponding to each frequency. This makes the whole `gather` operation redundant, as each MPI process can directly write the file corresponding to each frequency.

If instead the `dft_tot` file was being written as is by `rank = 0`, then the `gather` operation would make sense. But splitting the array into the constituent frequencies defeats the point.

This achieves the same result without the gather operation:

```
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.Get_size()
rank = comm.Get_rank()

start_freq = 100
end_freq   = 109
freq_range = np.arange(start_freq,end_freq+1)
no_of_freq = len(freq_range)

for fr_count in range(start_freq, end_freq+1):
    if fr_count % size == rank:
        dft = np.zeros((grid_size, grid_size))
        spec_csd = csd[:,:, fr_count]
        dft = DFT2D(spec_csd)  # Call the DFT2D function
        spec = np.array(np.real(dft))  # Spectrum or 2D_DFT of data[real part]
        print('Shape of spec', spec.shape)
        jj = np.around(freq[freq_range[rank]], decimals = 2)
        np.savetxt(f'Day_{count_day}_hour_{count_hour}_f_{jj}_hz.txt', spec.view(float))
```

Comment: I'm worried about no use of 'comm.gather' as what will happen if no. of tasks/jobs is higher than the size of the processors. Let, no. of tasks=10 and size=4, in that case data should be gathered in a sequence so how your proposed single for loop  serve the purpose? So, I think one need to use " res[i * size + k] = dft_tot[k][i]" with correct indexing.

Shape of res: 450 x 450, this is OK and the correct Shape of dft_tot: 10 x 450 x 450 [10 square matrices]

Comment: @Sam, your last part gives error when[condition:01] I choose no_of_freq=2, and size=no_of_processor=3 "    jj = np.around(freq[freq_range[rank]], decimals = 2)
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2". Besides, another condition(2) has tested where  no_of_freq=5, and size=no_of_processor=3: In that case there has been no error message but  5 output files saved in the sequence of [1,2,3,1,2] not in the order of [1,2,3,4,5]. The output .txt files should be saved in the order of [1,2,3,4,5] that is wanted though.